# How does mmap work when 2 programs map the same file

Tags: c, linux, mmap, virtual-memory, page-tables

I am trying to understand how `mmap` works while looking at [man mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).

As I understand it, it adds a mapping to the page table that maps between the file and the virtual address (which is the address that is given `void *addr`)

So, what happens when 2 programs map the same file?
Are there 2 entries in the page table, one for each program?

Comment: Each program has a separate MMU configuration basically. It's just that the same page is mapped in both processes.

Comment: When one process tries to write, does it write to the main memory(RAM) or directly to the file(Hard disk)?

Comment: @Lee: `man mmap:  MAP_SHARED Share this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are  visible  to other  processes that map this file, and are carried through to the underlying  file.   The  file  may  not  actually  be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called.`

Comment: Writing to arbitrary positions in a file which is opened by multiple files is in general a bad idea.

Comment: @Olaf: TIL IPC is a bad idea. Good to know.

Comment: So I don't understand, they both have different virtual addresses that point to the same physical addresses in the main memory which is loaded from the file?

Comment: @Lee: It seems to me that you *do* understand. That's exactly what it means.

Comment: Ok, so they both see the changes, but if a third process wants to read the file, it will see the change only when one of the processes does msync. right?

Comment: @Lee: not necessarily. *The file may not actually be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called.*  The modification may or may not be visible to the other processes mmapping the file or reading it via `read` or the `FILE*` stream API.  If one of the processes calls `msync()`, the modifications should be visible in all maps and for all yet unread portions of the file, bearing in mind that the `FILE*` streaming APIs may have buffered some data in internal unshared buffers.

Comment: @EOF: Not sure what you mean whit "TIL" (IPC i assume means interprocess communication). Anyway, notice the "in general"! No rule without exceptions.

Comment: Got it, thanks. How do I close the question..?

Comment: @chqrlie that should probably be posted as an answer

Comment: @EOF So the void pointer that mmap returns, does it point to the page in physical memry where the file is stored or the location where the mapping table is stored  ?

Comment: @john Neither. I'd recommend reading up on what a MMU does. Maybe what a modern OS does for memory protection. Finally, I'd recommend reading the manpage for `mmap()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So, what happens when 2 programs map the same file? Are there 2 entries in the page table, one for each program?

In modern operating systems, each process has its own page table for its memory, that may point to pages of physical memory shared with other user and kernel processes.

> With `MAP_SHARED`, this mapping is shared: updates to the mapping are visible to other processes that map this file, and are carried through to the underlying file. The file may not actually be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called.

This seems very interesting, but there are numerous caveats:

- The actual pages mmapped by both processes for the same file may reside at the same address or at a different address in each process, storing pointers into this *shared* memory may not allow the other process to use them as they might point to inconsistent addresses.
- The implementation may use the same physical memory pages for both mappings or not: for subtile reasons (cache strategies, out of sync reading...), even if it is the same physical memory, modifications done by one process to its memory may not be immediately reflected in the memory of the other process.

So the modification may or may not be visible to the other processes mmapping the file nor reading it via `read` or the `FILE*` stream API.

If one of the processes calls `msync()`, the modifications should be visible in all maps and for all yet unread portions of the file, bearing in mind that the `FILE*` streaming APIs may have buffered some data in internal unshared buffers: modifications in this area will not be reflected.

**Conclusion:** it is risky and unreliable to use these mechanisms to implement inter process communication.  The behavior may depend on system specific characteristics such as the OS strategies, the CPU and cache architectures, the type of RAM in use, the clock speed, and who knows what else.  It is safer to rely on proven APIs that may indeed be implemented using mmapped memory, but only if it is know to provide the correct semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The actual system implementation is different. At the risk of over simplification (and omitting paging here):

A mmap will map physical page frames to a file.

> So, what happens when 2 programs map the same file? Are there 2 entries in the page table, one for each program?

If two processes (P and Q) map to the same file, then P and Q will each have there own page table; each page table will have entry mapping to the same physical page frame (which could be mapped to different addresses within P and Q).